# How can I link two columns so that an edit in either is reflected in the other in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a monthly schedule in a Google Spreadsheet with some contact info in "A:D", two columns for the current date in "E:F", and then the dates for the current month in the rest of the columns.  Each day has two columns associated to it, one for the schedule and one for notes, and has the date at the top of the schedule column.  What I would like to do is have the current date's schedule and notes reflected in columns "E:F" such that editing cells in either the original column, or in "E:F", is reflected in the other, and have columns "E:F" update to the appropriate date each day.  From what I can gather I'll need a script to do this, but I don't have enough knowledge of JavaScript to know how to do so.

Here is a link to an example of this spreadsheet.

[Example Schedule](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JYmtI-aZPscNpNg-qDGVspxZo5mlsIrSn7l9D80zFaA/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for any help.

Edit:  Rows "1:3" are static and don't need to be linked between columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place something like this into the script that is attached to the sheet you want to work with

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  
  if (range.getColumn() == '6') {
      
    var startingCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var secondCell = startingCell.offset(0,1);
    
    var userInput = startingCell.getValue();
    secondCell.setValue(userInput);
  
  }
   
  
}
```

This will take the input from the column 'E' or column '6' and paste the input directly into the following column when it is edited.